# Is there a known problem with ESTA form online?passport validity?

Tags: usa, passports, esta, applications

I have a passport which was issued on Oct 26, 2011 and expires on Jul 26, 2022. Therefore it is valid for 10 years and 9 months.

I am applying for an ESTA, but the website won't let me progress as it states:

"Passport Issuance Date more than 11 years from the Passport Expire Date."

Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you contact the CBP Info Center at (202) 325-8000 or 1-877-227-5511 for assistance https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue. It is triggered by the year. For example the system works if you have a validity of 10 years 11 months if the dates run from say Jan 2015-Dec2025 but as soon as the year overlaps from 2015-2025 to 2015-2026 it will stop working. I have phoned them about this a couple of times and they are aware of the problem but have offered no resolution as of yet except apply for a visa or get a new passport. I am hoping they fix it as it is clearly a coding issue of some sort.

Comment: Then it is subtracting the year numbers instead of counting the months and checking for > 132.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second report within 11 hours about ESTA problems with a passport that is valid > 10 years

- presumably with an UK passport

calling the link shown in @Traveller answer may be useful after reading the giving answer here:

- [ESTA with UK passport (valid > 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/150046/95267)

where I have incoperated the information supplied by you and the suggestion of @Traveller.